# Find the positive integer whose cube exceeds its square by 4624

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the positive integer whose cube exceeds its square by 4624 .

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What has this got to do with either "calculus" or "power-series"?

Comment: Solve $x^3 - x^2 = 4624$

Comment: So what will be the answer ?

Comment: Well, you can either use the cubic equation formula, or just try plugging in numbers.  The answer can't be very big, right?  (Or you can start by factoring $4624$.)

Comment: Note:  $16<\sqrt[3]{4624}<17$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2(x-1)=4624=2^417^2,\tag1$$

Since $x^2$ is a divisor of $2^417^2$ it can take on only the values $2^2,2^4,17^2,2^217^2$. From these only $x=17$ satisfy (1).

Answer (score 0):

Finding the solution with WolframAlpha is easy, but not so interesting. A nicer way: $4624 = 4^2 \cdot 17^2$, so

$$x^3 - x^2 = 4624$$
$$x^2(x-1) = 4^2 \cdot 17^2$$
$$x \sqrt{x-1} = 4 \cdot 17$$

So $x$ divides $4 \cdot 17$, so you have to try $x = 1,2,4,17,2\cdot17,4\cdot17$.

Comment: As $x^3-x^2$ is close to $x^3$, only $x\approx17$ is likely.

Comment: @YvesDaoust in this case, it is really fast to consider $1,2,4$ (too small) and $2\cdot17,4\cdot17$ (too big), but your remark is really useful to exclude candidates in problems with more primes.

Comment: Taking the square root is not helpful, it hurts. In the second line, you need a square, and you need $x-1$ next to it. So $16\cdot 17^2$ is the only obvious option, if you take $x=1$ or $2$ or $4$, it can't work.

Comment: @orion the square root is really helpful! If $x$ is an integer, then $\sqrt{x-1}$ must be an integer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The cube root of $4624$ is between $16$ and $17.$

$16^3=4096<4624$ so if $1\le x\le16$ then $x^3-x^2< x^3<4624.$

If $x=17$ then $x^3-x^2=4624.$

Comment: If $x\ge18$ then $x^3-x^2\ge18^3-18^2=5508$;  $x^3-x^2$ is monotonic increasing for $x>\frac23$

Comment: $16^3<68^2=4624$ because $16^2<17^2$